# Trouble passing a value from HTML5 SELECT object to JS script

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a basic web page with an HTML5 SELECT object that has 3 elements populated in it via js/jQuery.  I want to take the value selected, and pass the value to a js file that runs a perl script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/RunPerlScript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1></h1>
        </header>
        <form name="myForm" method="GET" action="">
            <select id="cdLDAP" onchange="run_script_func(this.textvar 
                  <option/>
            </select>     
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS File:

```
    var selection = #cdLDAP.text
function run_script_func(val){
        window.alert=val;
   }
```

Based on my PHP admin console I know the script isn't executing.  My Perl script does work as expected, if I run it by itself, so I know it is not that aspect of my code.

Am I using the `onchage=""` element correctly?  and/or is it how the `RunPerlScript.js` file is structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the message box to work. The message box was being used to test the script was being called `onchange`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/RunPerlScript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1></h1>
        </header>
        <form name="myForm" method="GET" action="">
            <select id="cdLDAP" onchange="run_script_func(this.value)">
                <option/>
            </select>     
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the JS File:

```
function run_script_func(val){
        alert(val)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only got one

```
<option />
```

in your example.  For the change event to fire you probably need something to actually change.  Try adding another option.

Comment: Yes, by default I do, but when the page loads, and I hit the "down" arrow on the `select` object there is a list of items.  Those items are populated by the second `<script>` tag `js/main.js`

So, the goal is, when I hit the "down" arrow and select one of the vlaues, `onchange` I pass that value to the javascript.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't just run JS like that.  Whatever is in the onchange handler is treated as JavaScript, so that's just gibberish.  So you need to load that JavaScript like you do your other JavaScript and attach a handler to do what you want it to do.

Comment: I think I understand what tou are saying.  You are sayign change `<select id="cdLDAP" onchange="RunPerlScript.js">` to this `<select id="cdLDAP" onchange="run_script_func()">'   or more lie this ``<select id="cdLDAP" onchange="run_script_func(cdLDAP.text)">' 
and change my js file to be `var selection = #cdLDAP.text;`?  This is a learning process for me, so I am sorry if I am not understanding you.